# Postgresql inplace database upgrade

Tags: database, postgresql, upgrade

I'm trying to find a fastest way to move postgresql
database v9.1.20 from one server to another server
with postgres v9.3.10.

Scenario as follows:

Production server running Ubuntu 12.04
postgresql 9.1.20, database size appox 250g

Target server we are trying to relocate on is
Ubuntu 14.04 postgresq 9.3.10.

The very first attempt we are tried to experiment with
was to dump database (`pg_dump`) from old server and restore
it on the new server (`pg_restore`).

It has worked just fine but the time we spent to
relocate is about 4 hours (`pg_dump` takes 3 hours
and pg_restore takes 1 hour (network link 1g,
SSD disks on both servers).

Total downtime in 4 hours is not acceptable.

The next attempt was to use `pg_basebackup` instead of
`pg_dump`. The method has reduced backup time up to 40 mins
instead of 3 hours which is acceptable.

However we cannot use dump provided by the `pg_basebackup`
due to version incompatibility.

I had read many articles on how to provide inplace database
upgrade but it seems they are all referring to upgrade on the
SAME server.

So my question - how I can upgrade the database backup produced
by the `pg_basebackup` on the server without having previous
postgresql serve binaries installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to pipe the output  of `pg_dump` directly into a `psql`? Something like `pg_dump -h host1 dbname | psql -h host2 dbname` Btw: why don't you upgrade to a more recent version like 9.4 or 9.5?

Comment: You could do a (binary) copy of the old version (binaries+data) to the new machine (compile and) install the new version there and perform a --link ("in-place")  upgrade on the new machine.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgupgrade.html [start with a dry-run, of course. with the old installation still running on the old machine]

Answer (score 1):

You can perform upgrade using [repmgr](http://www.repmgr.org) and [`pg_upgrade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgupgrade.html) with minimal downtime (several minutes).

1. On master (postgresql 9.1) enable streaming replication. DB restart is required

   ```
   hot_standby = on
   wal_keep_segments = 4000 # must be hight enough for standby to catch up
   ```
2. On standby server install PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.3. On both servers install repmgr 2.0. Because repmgr 3.x versions work with PostgreSQL 9.3 or higher.
3. Synchronize master and standby server:

   ```
   repmgr -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -p 5432 -d repmgr -U repmgr --verbose standby clone -h psql01a.example.net --fast-checkpoint
   ```

   Underneath `pg_basebackup` should be used. So this method is pretty much the same as the one you've described.
4. Once cloning is finished you can start register standby:

   ```
   repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby register
   service postgresql start
   ```

   This would allow standby to catch up changes committed on the master during replication.
5. With both databases running (in sync) check if upgrade is possible:

   ```
   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade --check \
     --old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main \
     --new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main \
     --old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin \
     --new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin -v
   ```
6. If you pass upgrade checks you have to stop the master. Now the downtime period comes. Promote standby to master.

   ```
   postgres#: repmgr standby promote
   service postgresql start
   # if everything looks ok, just stop the server
   service postgresql stop
   ```

   The fastest upgrade method is using links:

   ```
   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade --link \
     --old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main \
     --new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main \
     --old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin \
     --new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin
   ```

   Even with 200GB data the upgrade shouldn't take longer than few minutes (typically less than one minute). When things go south, it's hard to revert changes (but we'd still have functional master server). Once upgrade is finished, start the new server. Verify everything is ok and then you can safely delete the old cluster:

   ```
   ./delete_old_cluster.sh
   ```